# LAST_INSERT_ID doesn't work in my case

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                      usertabbrige(`tabId`,`uId`) 
                      VALUES 
                      ((LAST_INSERT_ID()),$userId)");
```

anything wrong with this query? It's wrap within my first stmt, which will insert a value into uId (PK) in other table. usertabbrige table contain a field uId which is a FK.

Comment: If something wrong is happening, are you getting an error message?  Are you getting a result different from what you expected?  Please provide more information.  Also, **NEVER** put a variable for interpolation into your SQL, use `prepare("... ?")` as a placeholder, then perform `execute($userId)` later.

Comment: how about using `mysql_insert_id()` instead of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

Comment: I used mysql insert id but it got 0 in value. that's strange, the previous query did run. But I run both query in one file. 

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fyp`.`usertabbrige`, CONSTRAINT `usertabbrige_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tabId`) REFERENCES `tab` (`tabId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your query. You dont know which insert statement was last in current session. You can insert to one table, and if you use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in another query, you dont actually know where `LAST_INSERT_ID()` came from.

As I can see you are using `PDO`. After you executed an insert query, save id:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO ...");
$lastInsertedTabId = $db->lastInsertId;
```

Use it in your next prepared statement

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                  usertabbrige(`tabId`,`uId`) 
                  VALUES 
                  ($lastInsertedTabId ,$userId)");
```

Comment: I try echo $stmt->error I got this

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fyp`.`usertabbrige`, CONSTRAINT `usertabbrige_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tabId`) REFERENCES `tab` (`tabId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: You should give sql schema for both `tab`, `usertabbrige` tables

Comment: I try to use the GUI and it did insert. damn it.